# Add a bash alias via a Makefile target

Tags: bash, makefile, alias

I want to add an alias to the current bash session via a Makefile command.

Here is what I did in the Makefile:

```
.PHONY: addalias
addalias:
   alias myalias="echo Hello World"
```

But it is not working as intended :

```bash
# make addalias
> alias myalias="echo Hello World"
# myalias
> command not found: myalias
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, as you're trying to modify a parent shell.

Comment: You cannot.  There is no way for a child process to modify the environment of any other process, including its parent.  Here you have your shell, then you run `make` (one child process), then `make` invokes a shell (a second child process) to run the `alias` command.  The alias is created in that last shell, then it exits and the alias is lost, then `make` exits.  It is not possible for that last shell to modify the environment of the first one.  Just like you can't run `bash -c 'alias myalias='echo hello world'` and have that take effect in the parent shell (nothing to do with make).

Comment: Why don't you want to use **make** for this? Wouldn't it be simpler to either type the alias command explicitly, or to put it into a file and source the file - so instead of typing `make addalias`, you would type `. addalias`. This would even save you 3 keystrokes....